# send data without use scalars()

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new in FastApi I want use fastapi orm. When I return value, I get an error. I do not want `scalars()` method.

I get this error:

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for BaseOperation response
> value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

This is my schemas.py

```
class Operation(BaseModel):
    id: int
    quantity: str
    figi: str
    instrument_type: str
    type: str
    date: datetime



class OperationCreate(BaseModel):
    id: int
    quantity: str
    figi: str
    instrument_type: str
    date: datetime
    type: str
    

class BaseOperation(BaseModel):

    data: Optional[List[Operation]]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

it is my router.py

```
@router.get("/",response_model=List[BaseOperation])
async def get_specific_operations(operation_type: str, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session)):
   
    query = select(operation).where(operation.c.type == operation_type)
    result = await session.execute(query)
    
    return {
        
        "data": result.all()
    }
```

I get

> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for BaseOperation response
> value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

But when I write

```
return {
        
        "data": result.scalars().all()
}
```

it works well but I do not want use `scalars()`

I also found this solution:

```
@router.get("/",response_model=BaseOperation)
async def get_specific_operations(operation_type: str, session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_async_session))-> JSONResponse:
   
    query = select(operation).where(operation.c.type == operation_type)
    result = await session.execute(query)
    data = [row._asdict() for row in result.all()]
    return {
        
        "data": data,
        
    }
```

but I want send result.all()

Comment: You're defining that you're going to return a List: `List[BaseOperation]` but you're returning a plain dictionary - so your response model is just `BaseOperation`, not `List[BaseOperation]`. Generally I'd recommend against wrapping the response inside a  `data` key if you're not returning anything else (and name it something more descriptive than `data` if you want to have a multilevel response). In this case you can set `orm_mode` on your custom base class instead, inherit from that in `Operation` and return `List[Operation]` with `return result.all()` in your controller.

Comment: If i change BaseOperation to Operation it will be work? @MatsLindh